# Having Some issues with google cloud messaging api for android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to gcm api for android and have for some time now i have being working on an android app to allow chatting between two users of the app. The app is such that a chat can only be initiated when one user opts to contact the other user. But my confusion comes in the manner i would be able to create a chatroom for these two users and for the other user to be able receive messages. since i found out that each user must subscribe to a topic inorder to receive messages in that topic. Would i have to subscribe all users to all possible topics or what? that is my big question but it seems it would have so much overhead considering i have 1000+ users. 
Please i need all the help i can get here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Would i have to subscribe all users to all possible topics or what?*

> [GCM topic](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging#sending_topic_messages_from_the_server) messaging allows your app server to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic.

It is not a requirement but it can ease the work for the server to send messages. In this [tutorial](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/), you will see that they have created a chat like environment using GCM without using the topic function.

**BUT** consider the effects on your server like how will it behave on the potential load when you use the topic messaging, especially the the message will trigger an interaction from the user to the server.